# Play framework template parameter - pass a subclass

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.1

I have a view template that accepts the following parameter:

```
@(groups: List[models.groups.AcademicGroup]
```

I have my Academic Group class:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AcademicGroup extends Model
```

and a subclass like this:

```
@Entity
public class SchoolClass extends AcademicGroup
```

calling my view template from within another template already works:

```
@views.html.panels.groups(schoolClasses.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[models.groups.AcademicGroup]])
```

What isn't working, is passing the sublass directly via the controller:

```
public static Result schoolClasses() {
    List<SchoolClass> schoolClasses = SchoolClass.find.all(); 
    return ok(groups.render(schoolClasses));
}
```

With this approach, I get the error message:

```
The method render(List<AcademicGroup>) in the type groups is not applicable for the arguments (List<SchoolClass>)
```

typecasting the list doesn't work. Is there anything I am missing or is there a way to implicitely accept a subclass as template parameter like you can do it for Java generics:

```
List<? extends AcademicGroup>
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, the same thing in Scala (and therefore, in the template) would be `List[+models.groups.AcademicGroup]` (note the plus sign).

Comment: Try passing a `List[_ <: AcademicGroup]`, which is equal to `List<? extends AcademicGroup>` in Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to serejja!

Passing `List[_ <: AcademicGroup]` works!

This is equal to `List<? extends AcademicGroup>`

Adding just a `+` sign as Carsten mentioned leads to a compiler error